# Hibernate mapping конструкции List<Map<String, String>> list

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, коллекции

Как замаппить конструкцию вида `List<Map<String, String>> list`, используя XML mapping Hibernate?

```
public class MyClass
{
 private List<Map<String, String>> list;

 // Геттеры, сеттеры
}
```

файл MyClass.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="MyClass" table="TBL_MY_CLASS" lazy="true">
// Как замаппить list?
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, приложите  [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: какой еще "минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример" может быть в заданном мною вопросе? Что в вопросе выше было не минимально, не самодостаточно и что вы собрались воспроизводить в вопросе механизма хибернейт-маппинга???
Но коли вам требуется - дополнил вопрос.

Comment: А как вы список мап планируете в базу положить? (можно по-разному)

Comment: вот в этом и вопрос) Не нашел как это сделать, вынес Map<String, String> в отдельный класс и уже замаппил как список объектов, где тоже есть список.